Wildcard rule for @storage_fn.on_object_finalized?
Currently, this Firebase function works fine
@storage_fn.on_object_finalized(
    bucket='XXX.appspot.com', 
    timeout_sec=540, 
    memory=options.MemoryOption.GB_32
)
def process_audio_file(event: storage_fn.CloudEvent[storage_fn.StorageObjectData]):

However, it is not efficient because it is triggered every-time there is update on the bucket, even though it is not an audio file.
I wish to have the following trigger rule. But, it doesn't work.
@storage_fn.on_object_finalized(
    bucket='XXX.appspot.com',
    path='{user_id}/audio/',  # Specify the folder within the bucket
    timeout_sec=540,
    memory=options.MemoryOption.GB_32
)
def process_audio_file(event: storage_fn.CloudEvent[storage_fn.StorageObjectData]):

May I know, is it possible to monitor specific folder using wildcard rule? If yes, what is the correct syntax?

This question is similar to: Cloud Function storage trigger on folder of a particular Bucket. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

It's not possible.  Cloud Storage triggers apply to an entire bucket and cannot be filtered by object prefix.

See also: this, this
